# PyTorch Geometric GCN Autoencoder with Flat Latent Space

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder, pytorch-geometric

I have a problem in which I have a series of observations, each of which is a graph of the same structure, but with different node features. I would like to learn a flat embedding of each graph of size 32x1.

My thought was to do this with an autoencoder. This would take the input graph, apply some graph convolutions, use a dense layer to map the graph to a 32x1 latent space, and then reconstruct the graph (using the same common structure) before applying a few more convolutions.

As far as I am aware, this is in contrast to the typical graph autoencoder framework, in which the latent representation is a graph of the same structure as the input but with latent representations of each nodes' features.

For this reason, I am not sure how to implement such an architecture using PyTorch Geometric. Namely, I am unsure how I go from the flat latent space back to a graph.

Is this possible, and if so, roughly how would I do so?

Comment: Let's say your graph consists of 64 nodes. So you apply spectral decomp to it and apply a dense layer to its spectral representation which gives you 32 features. Why not just use another dense layer to map the 32 features to 64 features and do spectral synthesis using the same eigen vectors?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on "apply the spectral decomp to it"? I am familiar with the spectral decomposition of a graph's adjacency matrix or Laplacian, but this would not contain any information about the nodes' features.

Comment: Everything you need to know is explained in detail in section 2.1 SPECTRAL GRAPH CONVOLUTIONS of [this paper on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02907.pdf) by Thomas N. Kipf. The idea behind it is that you can't define convolution in the "spatial" domain on graphs so you compute the graph's Fourier transform using spectral decomp and use the fact that [convolution in the spatial domain is equivalent to pointwise multiplication in the Fourier domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).

Comment: By limiting the support of the Fourier transform of the filters you use in your network you can decrease the dimensionality of the features you use to represent your graph.

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying. I will look into these sources.